# Trying to identify exact Lempel-Ziv variant of compression algorithm in firmware

Tags: compression, reverse-engineering, firmware

I'm currently reverse engineering a firmware that seems to be compressed, but am really having hard time identifying which algorithm it is using.
I have the original uncompressed data dumped from the flash chip, below is some of human readable data, uncompressed vs (supposedly) compressed:

[image: uncompressed]

[image: compressed]

You can get the binary portion here, should it helps: [Link](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1NpeS0UfGVLYsepYno9fi_7gHoAWtX8Ps?usp=sharing)

From what I can tell, it might be using Lempel-Ziv variant of compression algorithm such as LZO, LZF or LZ4.

gzip and zlib can be ruled out because there will be very little to no human readable data after compression.

I do tried to compress the dumped data with Lempel-Ziv variant algorithms mentioned above using their respective Linux cli tools, but none of them show exact same output as the "compressed data".

Another idea I have for now is to try to decompress the data with each algorithm and see what it gives. But this is very difficult due to lack of headers in the compressed firmware. (Binwalk and signsrch both detected nothing.)

Any suggestion on how I can proceed?

Comment: Somewhere in the device must be code to decompress or interpret that data. I would disassemble that code.

Comment: @MarkAdler I forgot to mention, but I did tried to reverse and recreate the function I think does the decompression. Unfortunately it failed to output any meaningful data so it was a failure, hence I decided to look for help on SO.

Comment: Supposedly compressed data (second picture) doesn't look compressed to me. It may have been serialised and just contain the words compressed (maybe it is for some other piece later on)? I would try finding a function that interprets/reads this data in the firmware, or try building my own using some form of binary data deserialisation. It feels that even a fastest compressor would render data (human) unreadable. If you still suspect it is compressed, try searching for a magic header byte(s) which can point you in a direction of a standard compressor used.

Comment: Looking into the linked data - I feel this isn't a full dump. It's _very_ small to be a firmware package. Unless it is some form of a trivial device. This may be some form of a header file that describes the content of firmware. Note there's also no difference in size between compressed and bin files, which looks suspicious.

Comment: @oleksii The binary I shared is just a very small portion I dd out from the firmware because for various reasons I'm not allowed to share the full firmware. 
About "It feels that even a fastest compressor would render data (human) unreadable." you mentioned, some compression algo such as lzo does render human readable data. You can try using "lzop" cli utility on the binary I provided. However serialization is a good point worth digging into!